# [ streamlit dynamic form : add and remove fields dynamically ]

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to create a form to dynamically add and remove "text_input" fields.
I am able to add a "text_input" each time I click on the "➕ Add field" button.

However, I am unable to correctly remove a "text_field".

What I have achieved so far:
Every time I click on the "❌" button, the last added "text_field" is removed.

However, I am unable to identify the occurrence of the button that is clicked on.

Below is the source code of the form.
Thank you for your assistance.

```
import streamlit as st

FIELDS = []
DELETES = []

if "fields_size" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.fields_size = 0
    st.session_state.fields = []
    st.session_state.deletes = []


def add_field():
    st.session_state.fields_size += 1


def delete_field():
    pass


st.header("Dynamic form ⚒️")

st.divider()

# fields and types of the table
for i in range(st.session_state.fields_size + 1):
    c1, c2 = st.columns(2)

    with c1:
        FIELDS.append(
            st.text_input(f"Field {i}", key=f"text{i}", label_visibility="visible"))

    with c2:
        DELETES.append(st.button("❌", key=f"delete{i}", on_click=delete_field))

st.session_state.fields = FIELDS
st.session_state.deletes = DELETES

st.button("➕ Add field", on_click=add_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to remove a specific field when you click the delete button next to it, but you currently only remove the last field added.

Here's how you can fix this:

[image]

```py
import streamlit as st

def add_field():
    st.session_state.fields_size += 1

def delete_field(index):
    st.session_state.fields_size -= 1
    del st.session_state.fields[index]
    del st.session_state.deletes[index]

st.header("Dynamic form ⚒️")
st.divider()

if "fields_size" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.fields_size = 0
    st.session_state.fields = []
    st.session_state.deletes = []

# fields and types of the table
for i in range(st.session_state.fields_size):
    c1, c2 = st.columns(2)
    with c1:
        st.session_state.fields.append(st.text_input(f"Field {i}", key=f"text{i}"))

    with c2:
        st.session_state.deletes.append(st.button("❌", key=f"delete{i}", on_click=delete_field, args=(i,)))

st.button("➕ Add field", on_click=add_field)
```

This code should work for you too. Let me know.